# How to use df[df['Event_gender']== 'X'] correctly in this case?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say: there is a data frame:

```
country       Edition     sports       Athletes           Medal  Event_gender
Germany          1990    Aquatics  HAJOS, Alfred          gold     X
Germany          1990    Aquatics  HIRSCHMANN, Otto       silver   X
Germany          1990    Aquatics  DRIVAS, Dimitrios      silver   M
US               2008    Athletics MALOKINIS, Ioannis     gold     M
US               2008    Athletics HAJOS, Alfred          silver   W
US               2009    Athletics CHASAPIS, Spiridon     gold     X
France           2010    Athletics CHOROPHAS, Efstathios  gold     X
France           2010    Athletics CHOROPHAS, Efstathios  gold     M
France           2010    golf      HAJOS, Alfred          silver   M
France           2011    golf      ANDREOU, Joannis       silver   W
Spain            2011    golf      BURKE, Thomas          gold     W
```

I want to find out How many countries have won a gold medal with an event gender equal to 'X'?

so i'm trying to solve it but I am stuck. I did:

```
df[df['Medal']== 'gold']['country'].nunique()
```

and now I have the count of the countries who have won gold Medal but I am struggling in adding

```
df[df['Event_gender']== 'X']
```

to the above logic to get the final result. Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, it is

```
df.loc[(df['Medal']=='gold') & (df['Event_gender']=='X'), 'country'].nunique()
```